# How should been set permissions for / , /home etc. freshly after instalation of ubuntu?

Tags: boot, permissions

i had a problem to boot Ubuntu 11.10 after instalation caused by lack of permissions on freshly set partitions (partitions made by disk utility on live CD). I gave all permissions to all files to any user. How i should set it back to work properly with Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

What command did you run exactly ? If you ran it recursively you will have to reinstall. If you simply ran `sudo chmod 777 /home` it can be fixed

```
sudo chmod 755 /home
sudo chmod 755 /
```

In the future, rather then changing ownership and permissions of system files, use sudo or gksu

```
gksu nautilus
```

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo